# Android Google maps show where am I pointing (direction)

Tags: android, google-maps

I would like to show in my application in google maps the directions where am I pointing. So this is a part of my code for now. When the user is clicking on the button to show the location I am first checking if his GPS (location) is enabled. Also if there is a better way to check this you can tell me.

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);         

        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() 
        {
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() 
            {
                LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                boolean enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if (!enabled) {
                      Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                      startActivity(intent);
                    }
                else if(enabled){
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is standard way to check GPS enable-disable but as per your code not required use else if ladder just else.

Comment: Ok do you know how can I show where am I pointing? Like when using navigation, there is an arrow beside your location showing where are pointing..

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right, This is the standard way java uses.